# Which techniques are available in Muay Thai for blocking/avoiding a high roundhouse kick to the head?

Tags: technique, kicking, muay-thai, sparring, defense

In Muay Thai, when an opponent delivers a roundhouse kick to your head, what options are available as a defense or counter measure?

I have seen blocking it with the arm on the side of the head in the path of the kick, blocking with the kick facing arm and a reinforcement from the arm on the opposite side as well, and I have seen the technique of leaning back. Are there any other techniques? Can the leg be grabbed for a possible sweep? Is it advisable to move into the kick instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how "in Muay Thai" fits in; what differentiates a Muay Thai response from any other?

Whether or not it's *advisable* to move in to the kick depends on many factors; obviously if you're not where the kick was targeted, the impact will be reduced, because physics.

Legs can be grabbed for sweeps, but capturing a leg that's at head height isn't intuitive, since you need to move the leg down before there's any way to capture it, unless you have giant Hulk hands.

Not just *leaning* back, but *moving* back is another no-brainer.

If it's a full-force kick you could duck since it'd be tough to chamber anything else to go after your lowered head quickly enough, but obviously that's very timing- and situation-dependent.